# Why is wszName incorrect?

Tags: c, windows, networking, tcp, ip

[WCHAR wszName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366836%28v=vs.85%29.aspx);

In the debugger displays multiple "squares" and each addressed 0xcdcd

```
printf("Description: %ws\n", pIfRow->wszName); //prints nothing
```

Is there a reason it can not get the name from XP?
(All other info in `MIB_IFTABLE` is correct)

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

0xcdcdcdcd indicates that wszName was never initialized.  It is the default value of heap-allocated memory in the Debug build.  Review the code that copies a string into wszName, it is not working.  Presumably the call to GetIfTable() failed or you're iterating the table wrong.